# Typecasting in C for each of the variables

Tags: c

What is the difference between the following two?

```
// uint8_t a; uint8_t b;

uint16_t first = (uint16_t)(a * b);

uint16_t second = (uint16_t)a * (uint16_t)b;
```

What could be the use cases of these two kinds of implementations?

Comment: In both cases, operands are promoted to `int` before multiplication. So if you're on a machine where `int` is 16-bit, the first approach will do a signed 16-bit int multiplication, but won't promote the second case because operands will already be unsigned. On any microcontroller with 32-bit ints, you will get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

The mathematical product of `a*b` is in the range [0...65,025].

If `unsigned/int` is 32-bit, no difference.

If `unsigned/int` is 16-bit, `a * b` risks *signed* `int` overflow and *undefined behavior* (UB).  Both `a, b` are converted to `int` prior to the multiplication and `a*b` may exceed `INT_MAX` (32,767).

`(uint16_t)a * (uint16_t)b;` is better.